# updating data without model with classRegistry

Tags: cakephp

I have a table called user_tasks. I do not have a model for that table and in my totally unrelated controller I have a need to update a single field in the user_tasks table.

This is what I have tried so far

```
 $user = ClassRegistry::init('user_tasks');

        $conditions = "user_id = ". $user_id;

        $userRows = $user->find('first', array('conditions'=>$conditions));



        $user->set(array(

           'task' => $level
        ));

        $user->save();
```

However it does not like $user->save(); and my table never gets updated. What can I do to make it work.

thanks

UPDATE:

In my try / catch block, 
I get this

```
{"errorInfo":["HY000",1364,"Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value"],"queryString":"INSERT INTO `mytable`.`user_tasks` (`subscription`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('Latest', '2015-04-09 15:08:51', '2015-04-09 15:08:51')"}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out. I have to send user id as well

so

$user = ClassRegistry::init('user_tasks');

```
    $conditions = "user_id = ". $user_id;

    $userRows = $user->find('first', array('conditions'=>$conditions));



    $user->set(array(

       'task' => $level,
       'user_id' => $user_id
    ));

    $user->save();
```

The above will create a new record. If you are updating a record then just pass a primary key. And if you are passing the primary key, then you do not need user_id etc. You just need the fields in the set that need to be updated.

Comment: On a side note, what you are showing here is a nice SQL injection vulnerability. Conditions are only being escaped when using the `key => value` array format! **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions**

Comment: isnt that what it does $user->find('first', array('conditions'=>$conditions));?

Comment: @Autolycus No. You’re passing a string containing an (un-escaped) variable. @ndm is saying to use an array instead, i.e. `$conditions = array('user_id' => $user_id)`. And I’m going to say just create a model and save yourself the hassle.